# Scan period of beacons in android not working as expected

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I am working with beacons in xamarin android. I want the scan to be done over 60 seconds and a period of 30 seconds to wait between the next cycle of scan.

```
public async void DetectAvailableBeacons()
{ 
        _monitorNotifier = new MonitorNotifier();

        _rangeNotifier = new RangeNotifier();

        _tagRegion = new Region("Region",null, null, null);

        _beaconManager.Bind(this);

        _beaconManager.SetBackgroundScanPeriod(60000);
        _beaconManager.SetForegroundScanPeriod(60000);
        _beaconManager.SetBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000);
        _beaconManager.SetForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000); 

        _rangeNotifier.DidRangeBeaconsInRegionComplete += RangingBeaconsInRegionComplete;

    }
```

The method `RangingBeaconsInRegionComplete` fills my list `foundBeacons` with the beacons detected.

Also, I have a method that gets all the available detected beacons as follows:

```
ObservableCollection<DetectedBeacon> BeaconLocator.GetAvailableBeacons()
{
    return !_paused ? foundBeacons : null;
}
```

Now, I call the method `GetAvailableBeacons()` as follows:

```
public void PopulateBeacons() {
   beaconsOnList = be.GetAvailableBeacons(); 
   PopulateBeacons();
}
```

My issue is that sometimes it is missing some beacons, that is some beacons are not being detected. Also, the interval of scan does not seem to be working properly. Can someone advise what is wrong ?

Comment: The code shown appears to be using some kind of translation layer on top of the open source Android Beacon Library.  Which beacon SDK does this use?  Is this a Xamarin C# setup?

Comment: Yes you are right this is a Xamarin C# setup.

Comment: This uses the altbeacon sdk.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your scan periods to take effect right away, the easiest solution is to move the calls to set them *before* the call to `bind` so it looks like this:

```
    _beaconManager.SetBackgroundScanPeriod(60000);
    _beaconManager.SetForegroundScanPeriod(60000);
    _beaconManager.SetBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000);
    _beaconManager.SetForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(30000); 

    _beaconManager.Bind(this);
```

By default, the scan will happen every 1.1 seconds and give you a result of all beacons seen in that period.  This is probably what you are seeing happening without the code change above.

With shorter scan intervals, it is common for beacons with low advertising rates (e.g. ones that advertise only once every second) to not appear in the detection list for a single scan cycle.   You can solve this by increasing the length of the scan cycle as you say you want to do, by increasing the advertising rate of the beacons, or building code logic that maintains a full list of beacons detected recently even if they weren't seen in the most recent scan cycle.

Short answer:  If you increase your scan period successfully, I suspect this problem will go away.

Comment: Yes. But I want the detected beacons to get displayed on my UI. I am getting the minor ID. How can I make them appear on my UI without calling the method recursively?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a Xamarin expert, so once you get into how to show something in the UI with that setup, you are beyond my expertise.

Comment: Haha. Ok. So my setup is that I get the major and minor value of each beacons detected and show them in a list on the UI. I am doing this recursively to update my UI with new beacons scanned.

Comment: I don't think you should use recursion in this case.  You will get a call to `RangingBeaconsInRegionComplete` every time the scan cycle ends with a list of beacons.  You should simply update your UI each time that method is called.